# Sqlite update does not effect

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

My update database query did not work. I search and read many topics but did not find the solution. Also I have a delete statement and it is working smoothly.

My code:

```
//Checking for any previously open connection which was not closed
[self closeAnyOpenConnection];

//SqLite query
NSString *fetchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Update Category Set CatOrder = '%d' where CatOrder = '%d'", withToIndex + 1, withFromIndex + 1];

const char *updateQuery = [fetchQuery UTF8String];

sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement = nil;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseReference, updateQuery, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // executes the sql statement with the data you need to update in the db
    sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);

    // clearing the sql statement
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

    //closing the database after the query execution
    sqlite3_close(databaseReference);
```

Comment: Log the error if the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails. Also check the result of `sqlite3_step`. Also, why do you only close the database if the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds? And why do you open and close the database so much? Open the database once at app startup and leave it open. Close it when done.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Problem caused by sqlite3_finalize. I called it previous method. And also I will remove all close and open database codes. I will call them only one time.